Does the Ending of Akuma No Riddle Make Sense?
Okay, so the ending of Akuma No Riddle makes zero sense to me. Why did everyone who died come back to life? Chitaru drank poison after Hitsugi killed herself with a dagger. Well, technically Chitaru almost killed Hitsugi, but she couldn't, causing Hitsugi to push the dagger into her chest. Nio was killed by Tokaku's hand and I sorta understand why/how Haru lived. Haru did have a pair of fake ribs so she lived. Didn't Sumireko Hanabusa die after Haru pretty much broke her fake arm, causing Sumireko Hanabusa to fall to her death as Haru dangled over the edge? And even if they *didn't * die, they were expelled if they couldn't kill Haru within 48 hours! So what in the world happened at the end of episode 12?????????



